# Simple jQuery if statement not switching between styles

Tags: jquery, css

This might seem like a rookie error here, but I actually can't figure it out being new to jQuery. I want to just simple make it so that when clicking on the div, the height toggles between 3em and 10em. What I don't understand is when clicking the div the 2nd time (after the first transition has applied), nothing happens.

I read on a similar post to use the .live() method, but this seems to fail also with a 'is not a function' error:

```
$('.flex-text.description').live('click', function(){
    if ($(this).css('height') == '3em') {
        $(this).css('height', '10em');
    } else {
        $(this).css('height', '3em');
    }
});
```

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed? A beginner explanation would be very helpful. Thanks for any advice.

```js
$('.some.thing').click(function() {
 if ($(this).css('height') === '3em') {
  $(this).css('height', '10em');
 } else {
  $(this).css('height', '3em');
 }
});
```

```css
div { background: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='some thing'>stuff</div>
```

Comment: If ever you have a scenario like this where it's not hitting the right clause, just check exactly what it is you're comparing, ie add `console.log("$(this).css('height')")`

Comment: `.live()` was removed from jquery sometime ago, change it to `.on`  `$(".flex").on("click", function...`

Comment: interesting comments, thank you - I will consider console logging next time :)

Comment: Check My answer Below hope it works. If it doesn't work leave a comment in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `height` property will return the value in *pixels*:

```js
$('.some.thing').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).css('height'));
});
```

```css
div { background: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='some thing'>stuff</div>
```

16 pixels are equivalent to one em, so just replace your `3em` condition with `48px`:

```js
$('.some.thing').click(function() {
 if ($(this).css('height') === '48px') {
  $(this).css('height', '10em');
 } else {
  $(this).css('height', '3em');
 }
});
```

```css
div { background: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='some thing'>stuff</div>
```

Comment: 1em = 16px?  In my browser,  in your example it's 18px at 100% and 18.9px at 90%  zoom  (but otherwise the part about height==px is spot on)

Comment: The height *starts out* at 18px (a bit more than one `em`), before the handler runs and changes things to either 3em (48px) or 10em (160px)

Comment: That's interesting, and ultimately a little weird :)    The actual px will also depend on the css `font-size` property, so will need to be tailored per use.

Answer (score 1):

Computed styles are not calculated in em units. The value returned will be in pixels.

```js
$('.some.thing').click(function() {
 console.log($(this).css('height'));
 if ($(this).css('height') === '48px') {
  $(this).css('height', '10em');
 } else {
  $(this).css('height', '3em');
 }
});
```

```css
div { background: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='some thing'>stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `em` values depends upon the `font-size`. The solution trick for this problem is to have a hidden `div` of equal `font-size` and `height:1em;` then you can get the value of 1em.

```
<div class='some thing'>stuff</div>
<div class='hidden thing'>stuff</div>
```

Add this `CSS`

```
div { background: red }
.some{
  height:3em;
}
.thing{
  font-size:20px;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
  height:1em;
}
```

Use class `thing` in both hidden and unhidden `div` since both of them has equal `font-size` and `hidden div` has `height` `1em` and unhidden has `3em` set initially;
Then add this below JQuery Code.

```
$('.some.thing').click(function() {
var emHeight = $(".hidden").height();
var em3=emHeight*3;
if (parseInt($(this).css('height')) === emHeight*3) {
        $(this).css('height', '10em');
    } else {
        $(this).css('height', '3em');
    }
});
```

You can also check on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/xo9juqd3/29/)

https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/xo9juqd3/29/

Comment: Hope it works in every situation. Did it work for you?? @user8758206

Comment: Glad to help you @user8758206. Does the answer you accepted works well???